# find duration and latency of a native iOS mobile application

Tags: ios, json, networking, native

I am trying to find out the duration and if it is possible the latency of a network call to an iOS native application. I already found the instruments tool and tried out different templates without success :(

To be more specific i want to get the duration of a call that is send over a glassfish server which runs on my local machine. The call sends a json object.

I hope you guys can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `NSURLConnectionDelegate` method here, if you are using NSURLConnection to send the request to your server.
When you set up the request, you can use

```
CFAbsoluteTime before = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

to get the exact time when you initiated the request.
Use Delegate method

```
connection:didReceiveResponse:
```

and inside it

```
CFAbsoluteTime after= CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
```

difference between after and before will give the exact duration.

Also use, `connectionDidFinishLoading:`
if you want to get the time when you have completely loaded the JSON response.